# FileStream Object throws Exception when Accessing the WebSite from Client Machine in the Same Nework

Tags: iis, iis-7, io, visual-studio-2010

When I try to run the WebApplication From Visual Stuido 2010 and Hosted WebService in the same Machine It works fine.

But when I access the same WebSite from different Machine..

I got this Exception

```
Could not find file 'c:\windows\system32\inetsrv\98280INFO000001TIF1.tif'. ErrorSource:mscorlibStackTrace:   at System.IO.__Error.WinIOError(Int32 errorCode, String maybeFullPath)
   at System.IO.FileStream.Init(String path, FileMode mode, FileAccess access, Int32 rights, Boolean useRights, FileShare share, Int32 bufferSize, FileOptions options, SECURITY_ATTRIBUTES secAttrs, String msgPath, Boolean bFromProxy, Boolean useLongPath)
   at System.IO.FileStream..ctor(String path, FileMode mode, FileAccess access)
   at Create_Page.butt_ok_Click(Object sender, EventArgs e)
```

The Piece of Code throws Exception in this Line.

```
 FileStream fstream = new FileStream(imgFile, FileMode.Open,FileAccess.ReadWrite);
```

Please help we got this Error on Deployment.

Comment: This seems more like a programming/debugging issue that would have a  better home on [so].

Comment: could you elaborate more?

Answer (score 0):

c:\windows\system32\inetsrv\98280INFO000001TIF1.tif

Is an unusual location for storing image files.  Perhaps you need to specify the full path.